# Using Node.JS to Issue a Command from a Text File

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, fs

For a class assignment, I am required to create a Siri like program that takes a command and an argument and returns some data from an API, or in one particular case, reads from a text file and executes the command in that file to get data on a particular song.  I understand how to read the files using the FS module, but I'm not understanding how to get it to actually use what is returned to make it a command and execute (what is essentially myPlayList(I Want It That Way).  Below is the code so far, split into Select Cases and Functions as well as what is in the text file. This is my first post and figured seeing the whole code would better give context as to what is going on.

```
var keys = require("./keys.js") 
var twitter = require("twitter");
var omdb = require("request");
var spotify = require("spotify");
var fs = require("fs");

var liriCommand = process.argv[2];
var searchTitle = process.argv[3];

var twitterKeys = keys.twitterKeys;

var twitterUser = new twitter({
    consumer_key: twitterKeys.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: twitterKeys.consumer_secret,
    access_token_key: twitterKeys.access_token_key,
    access_token_secret: twitterKeys.access_token_secret
});
//console.log(twitterUser); okay keys working

//Switch cases to call function based on liriCommand entered.
switch(liriCommand) {
    case "my-tweets":
    myTweets();
    break;

    case "spotify-this-song":
    myPlayList();
    break;

    case "movie-this":
    myMovie();
    break;

    case "do-what-it-says":
    randomPick();
    break;
}

//Function for pulling in last 20 tweets

function myTweets(){
    twitterUser.get('search/tweets', {q: 'burgeoningbaker', count: 20}, function(error, tweet, response) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log(tweet);
        }
    });
};

//Function for pulling in artist, song name, link to song and album with song via Spotify
function myPlayList(){
    if (!searchTitle){
        searchTitle = 'The Sign';
    }

    spotify.search({type: 'track', query: searchTitle}, function(err, data){
        if (err){
            console.log('Error occurred: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        //Handle Data
        var albumTrack = data.tracks.items;

        for (i=0; i < albumTrack.length; i++){
        console.log("Artist: " + albumTrack[i].artists[i].name);
        console.log("Album Title: " + albumTrack[i].album.name);
        console.log("Spotify Link: " + albumTrack[i].preview_url);
        console.log("Track Title: " + albumTrack[i].name);
        // } else if (!data && !err){
        // myPlaylist('The Sign');
        }
    };
    
};

//Function for using request to get OMDB movie information from movie object
// Move Title, Year of release, Rating, Country, Language, Plot, Actors, Rotten Tomato Rating, URL

function myMovie(){};

// Function to fire off if typed do what it says

function randomPick(){
    fs.readFile("random.txt", "UTF-8", function(error, data){
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
            console.log(data);

    });
};
```

This is the text file contents

spotify-this-song, "I Want It That Way"

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. strange assignment instructions - the reading from text file where the text file is only a 'command' and a parameter. is this what the assignment requested, or the way you interpreted? it seems to me this application would make more sense as a command line interface where you can just feed it song names, rather than updating a .txt file and then calling the application.

anyways, assuming `you want it that way` that you described, your function call is never actually passing the song name - notice that your function call fires myPlaylist() with no arguments:

`case "spotify-this-song":
    myPlayList();
    break;`

and myPlaylist doesn't take any arguments:

`function myPlayList(){
    if (!searchTitle){
        searchTitle = 'The Sign';
    }`

this `if` statement will always evaluate to true, since you never pass in a searchTitle. note that up top where you define `var searchTitle = process.argv[3];` perhaps indicates that the application is supposed to be designed as a command line interface.

Comment: Yes the initial function of myPlayList is to take a command line argument of what track you want to search for in the Spotify API. If the command is issued without a song title, default to searching for The Sign.  The last Case is where my focus is.  When that is called, it should look in to the text file and issue the command that is in there which should be to search for the track I want it That way.  

I didn't want to post the actual assignment instructions but can if it will make things more clear.

Comment: right - refer to my previous comment - your myPlayList function can't take a parameter other than the command line argument. so your solution is to modify it to do so

Comment: if that is the case, than it feels to me that it still loops back to trying to get to that file and issuing the command within.  Here are the instructions on what should be done...

node liri.js spotify-this-song '<song name here>'
* This will show the following information about the song in your terminal/bash window
    * Artist(s)
    * The song's name
 * if no song is provided then your program will default to
    * "The Sign" by Ace of Base

Comment: node liri.js do-what-it-says
Using the fs Node package, LIRI will take the text inside of random.txt and then use it to call one of LIRI's commands.
It should run spotify-this-song for "I Want it That Way," as follows the text in random.txt.  Maybe I'm having a case of needing to step away from the project and come back to it.

Comment: yea, i'm not sure what level of class this is, first year, second year, etc - but you're nearly there - let me know later if you can't get it and i'll see if i have time to post a solution

Comment: Okay yeah it is a boot camp.  Not sure if that matters or not, but I'll see what I can figure out on my own.  Like we both concur, I'm swimming around it.  There is something that I'm just overlooking.

Thank you for taking a look.